# How to transfer money from my Developer Account?

Tags: application-development

I have $22 in my developer account. I want to transfer this money to my paypal account. How can I do it?

Is there any limit for the transfer or any time we should wait.

Comment: Ubuntu developer account?. Then this is on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I got clarified.

Each and every quarter money which we got by developing will be credited.

Say for Jan-March we will get the amount at the end of the April to our Paypal email ID which we have synced.

There wont be any limit. And it is done only on quarterly basis